# Java8 variables scope

Tags: java, variables, scope

I took mock exam test as i am preparing for OCAJP exam and i came across this below question on Variables and Scope of Variables.

```
public class HelloWorld{
     static int x = 2;            
     public static void main(String []args){
        if(x>1)
        {
            x++;
            int x = 4;
        }
        System.out.println(x);
        final int x = 10;
     }
}
```

and the output for the above code is "3". 
But i am unable to figure out why the output is 3. I can understand that the "int x=4" within the if block will be seen outside the IF block. But should not "final int x = 10;" throw compiler off-track as there is already x as a static variable?

Comment: You can have local variables with the same name as a static or non static field.

Comment: There is no `int x=3` in the code.

Comment: Sorry @Arkadiy, that was a typo.

Answer (score 5):

Let's take this in code order.

```
static int x = 2;
```

This declares a static class variable named `x` that is initialized to `2`.

```
if(x>1)
```

This refers to the static class variable, because the other declarations of `x` haven't occurred yet.

```
    x++;
```

This increments the static class variable `x` to `3`.

```
    int x = 4;
```

This declares a new local variable `x`, distinct from the static class variable `x`, and initializes it to `4`.  This new local variable *shadows* the static class variable.  However, it immediately goes out of scope; its scope is limited to the `if` block.  It is not referenced after declaration and before it goes out of scope.

```
System.out.println(x);
```

This prints the only `x` in scope, the static class variable, which is `3`.  The local `x` declared above is out of scope and no longer shadows the static class variable.

```
final int x = 10;
```

This declare another new local variable `x`, also distinct from the static class variable `x` and distinct from the already out of scope `x` previously declared in the `if` block, and initializes it to `10`.  This new local variable *shadows* the static class variable.  However, it also immediately goes out of scope; its scope is limited to the `main` method block.  It is also not referenced after declaration and before it goes out of scope.

The main points are:

- A local variable can *shadow* a class variable of the same name.  However, it only does so in its own local scope.
- Variables not yet declared do not shadow the class variable yet.